# HashMap with generic value and as an attribute

Tags: java, generics

I'm working on a project about management of students with Collections as a data storage and ran into trouble. I used a HashMap which is used as an attribute of the class `Gestion` which is a generic class. I created a method `add` to it for adding `etudiants` or `mention` elements for the HashMap attribute. I'm new to generics and I don't understand the bug.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GestionEtudiants <T>{

   private HashMap<Integer, T>  gestion;

    public GestionEtudiants() {
        gestion = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void setgestion(HashMap gestion){
      this.gestion=gestion;

    }

    public HashMap getgestion(){
    return this.gestion;
    }

     public <T>void addGestion(T object) {

        this.gestion.put(object.Hashcode(), object);
     }
}
```

Comment: If you're new to generics, why do you think this class should be generic? It shouldn't be. Learn to **use** generic types before trying to **create** generic types. And before using generic types, learn what a Map is for, what its principle is, and what it allows doing. Google for "Java collections tutorial".

Comment: and btw `object.Hashcode()` will surely not compile

Comment: In addition to the above, you haven't even told us what the bug is, or given a complete example. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: A closing brace is also missing, another compilation error other than Hashcode()

Answer (score 0):

just change this method as :

```
public void addGestion(T object) {

        this.gestion.put(object.hashCode(), object);
     }
```

and after that close the class.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why this makes a difference.